# How to use broadcast DATE_CHANGED? (android)

Tags: java, android

```
         <receiver android:name="com.BillManager.DateChanged">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
                 </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

in class...

```
 if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
    { 
          Log.d("DateChanged","DateChanged");
    }
```

Hello,
 I am devloping an Android app and I use this broadcast to announce when the user changes the date manually.
 For some reason I get the broadcast at 12:00 without changing the date manually.
 Does anyone have an explanation why is it?

Comment: 12:00 = midnight? The date changes then too. [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java#AlarmManagerService.ClockReceiver.scheduleDateChangedEvent%28%29) seems to be responsible.

Comment: Date_Changed action is for when user change the date in device and not for date changes in device.